# fake outgoing connection to another ip ?? is that possible

Tags: linux, networking, resolve

simply 
i have a script which is crypted and compiled , when run to check for a file if exist or not
on a remote server which ip is 1.x.x.x
problem the server 1.x.x.x is not any more working
so iam not able to run the script again , as it must curl for that file on the dead server 1.x.x.x

i want to put the files on a new server with ip 2.x.x.x ,

and my machine has another ip 3.x.x.x where i run the script 
is that possible to configure my machine  where i run the script
to connect to ip 2.x.x.x rather than 1.x.x.x

or fake server when script try to connect to 1.x.x.x , the machine redirect connection to 2.x.x.x

thanks

Comment: Use NAT to redirect the connection.

Comment: `iptables -j REDIRECT`

Comment: i would like to mention that the both ip are out of my machine ,

Comment: You can still use NAT/redirection on the machine where the script is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You wouldn't even need a remote server, simply add that specific IP-address as an alias to your own machine, make that file available on the new interface and bob's you uncle.

```
# ifconfig lo:1 1.2.3.4 netmask 255.255.255.255

# ping 1.2.3.4
PING 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.2.3.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 1.2.3.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms

#  ifconfig lo:1 1.2.3.4 netmask 255.255.255.255 down
```